# AWS S3 Download file hangs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 for storing text files and then download them using a Windows Service from EC2. About 50% of the time I start the service, the service hangs while downloading the file from S3. This is the code I'm using:

```
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = BucketName;
            request.Key = FilePathAndName;
            using (GetObjectResponse response = objClient.GetObject(request))
            {
                string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];                   

                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader =
                        new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }                       
                }
            }
```

I also tried this code, while ReadAllResponseStream() is a method that reads the stream manually, instead of using reader.ReadToEnd():

```
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = BucketName;
            request.Key = FilePathAndName;
            using (GetObjectResponse response = objClient.GetObject(request))
            {
                //string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
                //Console.WriteLine("The object's title is {0}", title);

                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                {
                    byte[] s3Data = ReadAllResponseStream(responseStream);
                    responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s3Data, 0, s3Data.Length);                      
                }
            }
```

If I'm using each variation of code from local premises (outside of EC2) it seems to work fine.

Comment: It might be a network or OS issue... I'm making few tests, since local development environment seems fine. EC2 machines are connected as a virtual private cloud, and the way some of the machines are connected to the internet using AWS might have some initialization up time issue.